# How do I add back the 'Open Terminal' option in the right-click context menu on the desktop in Gnome on CentOS 8?

Tags: centos, gnome, gnome-terminal

I have tried many searches for this information to no avail. Most of the information talks about installing the `gnome-terminal-nautilus` and `nautilus-open-terminal` packages, but they had no effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You will have to use a gnome extension:

https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1465/desktop-icons/

GNOME 3.28 has removed the ability to place files on the desktop, hence you can't open the terminal either.